# how to transform many columns of a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a simple data frame

```
d <- data.frame(var1=c(5,5,5),var1_c=c(5,NA,6),var2 =c(6,6,6),var2_c = c(8,6,NA))
```

with a lots of lines, and a lots of variables, all labeled "varXXX" and "varXXX_c", and I want that everytimes there's a NA in a varXXX_c to replace the NA with the value in the varXXX variable.
In short, I want to do :

```
d[is.na(d$var1_c),"var1_c"] <- d$var1[is.na(d$var1_c)]
```

but try to find a better way to do this that copy paste and change "1" with the number of the variable.

I would rather find a solution in base R or dplyr, but would be grateful for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` to find the column names that start with `var` followed by numbers (`\\d+`) followed by `_` and followed by `c`.  Similarly, we have another set of logical index for `var` followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) till the end of the string (`$`) and then do the subset of columns based on the index and change the NA values (`is.na(d[i1])`) to the corresponding elements in 'd[i2]`.

```
i1 <- grepl("var\\d+_c", names(d))
i2 <- grepl('var\\d+$', names(d))
d[i1][is.na(d[i1])] <- d[i2][is.na(d[i1])]
```

NOTE: This is based on the assumption that the columns are in the same order.

Comment: woah ! thank you for this beautiful and efficient solution ! The problem for me is that my data frame contains other variables than varXXX/varXXX_c type variables, and that I am not sure how the columns are sorted (and your solution, correct me if I'm wrong, is highly dependent on this condition).

Comment: @Malta In that case, do a second grep i.e. `i2 <- grepl('var\\d+$', names(d))` and use 'i2'